# Typescript Mongoose Middleware - typing the args of "post" callback function

Tags: typescript, mongoose

Using typescript and mongoose:
Been doing a bit of reading and can not figure out what is going on... I am adding mongoose middle ware to customize a duplicate error message, but the arguments of the callback are not typed. As you can see below, I have to force the any type to resolve the implicit any error.

```
// Define Schema...
// Then call this:
ProductSchema.post("save", function (error: any, doc: any, next: any) {
  if (error.code === 11000 && error.name === "MongoServerError") {
    next(
      new ApolloError(
        "A product with this name, category, and subcategory already exists. Please add it to your kit instead of creating it.",
        "DUPLICATE_PRODUCT"
      )
    );
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

// I then call the .model() method after this
```

I have tried passing generics with Query, `ProductSchema.post<Query<Product, Product>>(...)`

If I remove the `doc` argument, the errors then leave but the code does not execute on duplicate documents.

Any suggestions would be great! I'd like to have it typed if possible...! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and although a little bit late this answer can save time for others:

In Mongoose versions above 6.8 you can add `{ errorHandler: true }` to "[help TypeScript out](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/12583)" and `error:any` to skip `Property 'code' does not exist on type 'NativeError'` error.

```js
ProductSchema.post("save", { errorHandler: true }, function (error: any, doc, next) {
  if (error.code === 11000 && error.name === "MongoServerError") {
    next(
      new ApolloError(
        "A product with this name, category, and subcategory already exists. Please add it to your kit instead of creating it.",
        "DUPLICATE_PRODUCT"
      )
    );
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

And finally, "unique" is not a validator in Mongoose, a gotcha is that it requires a field index to work [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator). So, in the model, you can add `ProductSchema.index({ "name": 1, "category": 1, "subcategory": 1}, { "unique": true });`